# Capturing screenshot and parsing data from the captured image

Tags: python, image, parsing, screenshot

I need to write a desktop application that performs the following operations. I'm thinking of using Python as the programming language, but I'd be more than glad to switch, if there's an appropriate approach or library in any other languages.

The file I wish to capture is an HWP file, that only certain word processors can run.

1. Capture the entire HWP document in an image, might span multiple pages (>10 and <15)
2. The HWP file contains an MCQ formatted quiz
3. Parse the data from the image that is separate out the questions and answers and save them as separate image files.

I have looked into the following python library, but am still not able to figure out how to perform both 1 and 3.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correctly , you need to extract text from image.
For this one you should use an OCR like tesseract.
Before using an OCR, try to clear noises from image.
To split the image try to add some unique strings to distinguish between the quiz Q/A

Comment: Actually, extracting text is not what I am looking for. 
I need to extract the images(cropped one corresponding to the questions and the answers) separately.

Also the file format and content is not something I can modify, so I can't put it unique string to differentiate the questions and answers.

Comment: I would still use an OCR becuase you can find "?" char and the number of the question/answer and match them (as long their corresponding) . The OCR gives you an elegant way to differenate Q/A instead of just cropping by spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
Although using an OCR seems like a good idea, the consistency of the question pattern(use of "?", or regular question numbers or in some instance images as questions) can be an issue.

I will definitely look into using the Tesseract library